# How do you print double * in c?

Tags: c, printing, double

i am trying to print a double and have been using %lf throughout my code, but when i compile the program two of the printf doubles come up with a warning saying:
format specifies type 'long double' but the argument has type
      'double *' [-Wformat]
what format should i use to print this?

Comment: `printf("%f\n", *my_double_pointer);` That is, dereference your `double *` variable. Assuming you want to print the double value and not the actual pointer value.

Comment: Did you read the [documentation of `printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) ? Please provide some [mre] in your question..., so [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62228892/edit) it for improvement. Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/)

Comment: Why don't you show us the relevant parts of your code instead of describing your code?

Answer (score 2):

You should pass the double rather than a pointer to it.

You apparently have something similar to

```
double d = ...;
double *p = &d;
printf("%lf\n", p);
```

Replace the last line with

```
printf("%f\n", *p);
```

Also note the removed `l`, which is for use with integer conversion specificers.